# How do i make a value retrieved from a Microsoft word document a string in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a powershell script that will read a value from a table in a Microsoft word document. But when I try to write that value to a text file to be used later by a batch file, it does not work as desired. The text file displays the value with a dot on the end. Then when I read the value from the text file in a batch file it is all messed up.

```
$wd = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$wd.Visible = $true
$doc = $wd.Documents.Open("C:\Users\jxh\Desktop\taskids.doc"  )
$iTable = $doc.Tables.Item(1)

$r = $iTable.Rows.Count
$c = 1
Write-host $r "x" $c
$content = $iTable.Cell($r, $c).Range.Text 
Write-host $content

 if ($content) {
$r = $iTable.Rows.Count - 1
$c = 1
Write-host $r "x" $c
$content = $iTable.Cell($r, $c).Range.Text #| Out-File C:\filename.txt
Write-host $content 
$iTable.Cell($iTable.Rows.Count, $c).Range.Text=$content+1  }

$content > C:\filename.txt


$doc.Close()
$wd.Quit()
# Stop Winword Process
$rc = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wd)
```

Answer (score 0):

The character you are seeing in your `.txt` file is a BELL character.  You can use the regex operator to strip that out like this:

```
$content -replace "\a","" > 'C:\filename.txt'
```

UPDATE: This shows how to remove all characters not in a range, not just a single character.  In this example, anything which is not a number character is replaced with a null character:

```
$content -replace "[^0-9]","" > 'C:\filename.txt'
```

Comment: That gets rid of the dot, but I still am not able to get the value correctly. The value written to the file is 86591 but when I try to retrieve the value in my batch file I get  ■8
 ■8 as the value returned from the text file

Comment: You could try replacing any character which is not in a specified range.  So if you only want numbers, your replace might look like this $content -replace "[^0-9]",""

Comment: That still does not fix the problem. It looks fin when I open it in notepad, but when I retrieve the value I still get the same result. Maybe it has something to do with Microsoft Word encoding or something?

Comment: Try dumping the output of $content to the console as ascii values of the string. Something like this  `($content -replace "[^0-9]","").ToCharArray() | %{ [int]$_ }`   If the `-replace` is working correctly, it should filter out anything but character values '0' through '9'.